# Is there a way to include files in git, but not the changes / data inside the files

Tags: xml, git, github

with the programm I work, I need many temp_*.xmls for multiple reasons (debugging, data transformations etc.).
all of those xmls start with "temp_" and after that some kind of name depending on its purpose.
e.g. "temp_DataFromDatabase.xml" is a temporary file for Data from a Database.

now, when I upload my repository, its always loaded with tons of temp_ xmls. I do need to upload them, but I dont need the data inside the xml, because that will always change and is only temporary anyways.

I found some stuff like exclude and ignore, assume unchanged etc, but that didnt really help me. When I add new temp_ xmls, they should also be uploaded and added, but not the data inside, as I said. Also, when I delete those xmls, they should not be included in the "git add"

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Why do you need to upload them, if you don't want to upload their contents? It seems to me like `temp_*` in your `.gitignore` would make sense, and just never upload them. Can you spell out more clearly why you want the files uploaded if you don't want their contents?

Comment: But... if you do in fact want to upload empty placeholders, you could create the files using `touch` to make them empty (or just edit their contents out). Then `git add/commit/push` the empty placeholders. Then use "assume unchanged" so further modifications (and contents) don't get included in future commits and thus don't get uploaded.

Comment: basically I need the "temp files" because they are in a sequence, eg. Start of programm -> some stuff -> temp_file -> some stuff -> end of programm. if the temp file is missing, the sequence is missing the temp file and will break. editing out the contents would take to long I think. Some projects have well over 100 temp files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do, is set the [assume unchanged](https://dev.to/nickraphael/git-assume-unchanged-for-when-you-want-git-to-ignore-an-edit-for-a-while-2lig) option to prevent git from tracking local changes to those files once they already exist in git repo:

```sh
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged "temp_*.xml"
```

But this only affects your local working directory, if you or someone else creates new clones of the repo they will need to remember to run this command again.

Comment: so when I create new temp_*.xml files, I'll need to add them, and after that I can just run this command so git will ignore all of them?

is it possible to do `git add .`, then what you said, and then `git commit`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  What you're asking for is a special case of the general question, “How do I ignore changes to tracked files?”  That question is [answered in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

The proper solution is to avoid checking these in in the first place.  If you need to keep track of which temporary files should exist, you could put a script into your repo to create empty ones with appropriate names or otherwise generate the files you need, which is going to be more robust and avoid bloating your repository.